# Netbeans scala plugin problems with ant

Tags: scala, netbeans, ant

I have installed NetBeans 7.3.1 on Mac OSX 10.8.4 with scala.

Could not load definitions from resource scala/tools/ant/antlib.xml. It could not be found.
init:
deps-jar:
/Users/.../NetBeansProjects/ScalaApplication2/nbproject/build-impl.xml:405: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/..../NetBeansProjects/ScalaApplication2/nbproject/build-impl.xml:238: Problem: failed to create task or type scalac
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any / declarations have taken place.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

I have added J-Dscala.home=%SCALA_HOME% to the netbeans.conf file
and on the mac terminal 
 echo $SCALA_HOME 
gives
/usr/local/Cellar/scala/2.10.1/libexec
where 
lib directory lives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The netbeans error message could be worded more clearly.

One issue is that you are using MS Window's syntax %SCALA_HOME% for evaluating your environment variable. The Unix syntax is $SCALA_HOME or ${SCALA_HOME}.

The following works for me:
First add the following line to **.profile**

```
export SCALA_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/scala/2.10.1/libexec
```

and append the following to netbeans_default_options in **netbeans.conf**

```
-J-Dscala.home=/usr/local/Cellar/scala/2.10.1/libexec
```

I'd prefer to just list the scala home directory in one place to make upgrades more foolproof, but referencing ${SCALA_HOME} from netbeans.conf didn't work for me. Maybe the environment variable needs to be defined elsewhere to be visible from netbeans.conf